# Exact Differential Equations $(axy^2+by)dx+(bx^2y+ax)dy=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy=0$ is said to be a perfect differential when

$$\frac{\partial (M(x,y))}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (N(x,y))}{\partial x}$$

Let $M_y=\frac{\partial (M(x,y))}{\partial y}$ and $N_x=\frac{\partial (N(x,y))}{\partial x}$.

In case if:

$\frac{M_y-N_x}{N(x,y)}$ is only a function of x only (say $f(x)$) then it has a integrating factor $e^{\int f(x)dx}$.

But if $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N(x,y)}$ is a constant then what will be the integrating factor?

> Say for this problem:
>   $(axy^2+by)dx+(bx^2y+ax)dy=0$

Is there any other method to solve this differential equation?

Comment: You can consider any constant function  as a function of $x$ as well as a function of $y$. Here you can consider as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 5):

***Remark***:

If $Mx-Ny\not=0$ and the equation can be written as $f(xy)y\,dx+F(xy)x\,dy=0$ then $\frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$ is an integrating factor of the equation.

Here the equation is $(axy+b)y\,dx+(bxy+a)x\,dy=0$. So , $I.F.=\frac{1}{(a-b)(x^2y^2-xy)}.$

Can you proceed further ?

Comment: Multiplying by the I.F. the second part reduces to $d(x^ay^b)$ which is a perfect differential.But the first part is not reduced. I suggest you to try it on a sheet.

Comment: How do you get that solution?

Comment: This is not the answer.just check your answer by differentiating. You won't get the previous equation.

Comment: yeah, i will see where i went wrong. Please show  your method

Comment: I dont understand how are f and M connected? And how do we know that this is the integrating factor. Can you please add it to your answer.

Comment: First tell me what's your level ? I don't know why this simple thing is unable to understand to you..First of all write the equation in the form $M\,dx+N\,dy=0$. Then if $M=f(xy)y$ and $N=F(xy)x$ then the integration factor will be $\frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$.

Comment: If you know **this :** $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N(x,y)}$ is only a function of x only (say $f(x)$) then it has a integrating factor $e^{\int f(x)dx}$... then my answer should be understand...because it is one type of case where the equation is NOT exact..

Comment: If $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N(x,y)}$ is  a function of x only (say $f(x)$) then **how you know that** integrating factor $e^{\int f(x)dx}$ ????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27550/discussion-between-yasir-and-s-panja-1729).

Comment: I don't want to discuss further about it...Firstly read your text book carefully and then post a question with discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$ then integrating factor of equation
$$(axy^2+by)dx+(bx^2y+ax)dy=0$$
is
$$\\\frac{1}{{{x}^{\frac{2 b+a}{b+a}}} {{y}^{\frac{b+2 a}{b+a}}}}$$
and solution
$$\\\frac{x^2y^2-xy}{{{x}^{\frac{2 b+a}{b+a}}} {{y}^{\frac{b+2 a}{b+a}}}}=C$$